# Is it possible to mix filetypes in an S3 bucket for AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I've got a set of files I want to put into AWS S3 so I can read them using AWS Athena. The directory structure looks like:

```
brand=mrwhippy/model=flake/serialnumber=0001/time=2019-09-11T02:57:33+0000Z/
```

But within that directory I've got several files of different types - INI and JSON.

1. Can I setup AWS Athena to handle this or do I need to convert the INI files to JSON?
2. If they're all JSON can I use the filenames to differentiate the values or do I need to put this at the base of the JSON tree? For instance:

Config.json:

```
{
    "Config":{
        "Setting1": 1,
        "Setting2": "Cheese"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A table can be defined with a `LOCATION` that points to a directory.

Athena will process all files in that directory (including sub-directories) as belonging to that table.

Therefore, **all files under that path need to be in the same format**.